# Configurations for jenga

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

I came up with the following problem a couple days ago.

"Considering the rules and constraints of standard Jenga gameplay, how many combinatorially unique, structurally stable, practical configurations can a Jenga tower have?"

By practical, I mean configurations that can be feasibly achieved during actual gameplay, taking into account the typical moves players make and the inherent stability required to prevent the tower from collapsing prematurely. It emphasizes configurations that players are likely to encounter or aim for, rather than improbable or near-impossible arrangements.

I am trying to look at this under a primarily combinatorial lens rather than a physics based one.

(Also sorry if this is worded poorly, if you have any ideas to word it better let me know.)

I just have no idea where to even start, does anyone have any ideas? I have been staring at a blank page for so long.

There are 54 blocks with 3 blocks per layer, for 18 layers

Comment: Dies this help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrSEfX82WbE

Comment: Please give a valuable reference about Jenga game.

Comment: It is a certainly interesting problem, although one needs to clarify what "structurally stable" structure means in terms of combinatorics. Interpreting this as "the Jenga block configuration being at a stable equilibrium, resistant to sufficiently small perturbation", I think it can be translated into an unambiguous combinatorial rule, relating the configuration of each level and the COM of blocks above it. Although I am skeptical about some simple closed-form formula for the number of possible configurations for each number of blocks given, a dynamic programming approach would work.

Comment: Typically, a layer either has the two outer bricks, or the center brick, or the center and a side brick, or all three bricks. This makes it a combinatorics exercise to calculate the number of possibilities. It is also the assumption made in the MathSE question [Solvability of jenga](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4193298/26369), which the video Hagen von Eitzen linked is based on.

Comment: I think many people are familiar enough with Jenga to know what is it about, but I'm pretty sure most people won't know how many pieces the game have. Why would you ask a question like this without giving that information?

Comment: Yeah I should have clarified, that is my bad! Edited

Comment: Is there a reason you've edited the question as to avoid referring to the game by its published name?

Comment: @Carmeister Oh, I was trying to edit something else and it wasnt working so I went on my computer to see if editing worked, and I just changed a random detail, and it said it didn't

Comment: Without defining "practical" mathematically, this isn't a well-posed problem. Furthermore, "emphasizes" doesn't make sense to me in the context of counting things—either a configuration is counted or it's not.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring the top layer, every layer has either all three blocks, one block in the middle, or any of the three possible combinations of two blocks. The number of configurations in one layer with a given number of blocks is thus described by the generating function $x+3x^2+x^3$. For a given number of $n$ layers the generating function thus becomes $(x+3x^2+x^3)^n$. If $a_n$ is the total number of configurations with $n$ blocks, we get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(x+3x^2+x^3)^n=\frac1{1-x-3x^2-x^3}.$$ Now consider the top layer. All possible combinations of the three positions either having a block or not are possible, except for the empty combination. This layer thus has the generating function $3x+3x^2+x^3$. If $b_n$ is the total number of configurations with $n$ blocks, including the empty configuration we get $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n=1+(3x+3x^2+x^3)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=1+\frac{3x+3x^2+x^3}{1-x-3x^2-x^3}=\frac{1+2x}{1-x-3x^2-x^3}.$$ With partial fraction decomposition, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n&=\frac{1-2\sqrt2}{4(x+1-\sqrt2)}+\frac{1+2\sqrt2}{4(x+1+\sqrt2)}-\frac1{2(x+1)}
\\&=\frac{3+\sqrt2}4\frac1{1-(\sqrt2+1)x}+\frac{3-\sqrt2}4\frac1{1-(1-\sqrt2)x}-\frac12\frac1{1-(-1)x}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{3+\sqrt2}4(\sqrt2+1)^n+\frac{3-\sqrt2}4(1-\sqrt2)^n-\frac12(-1)^n\right)x^n
\end{align}
Thus we get the closed form expression
$$b_n=\frac{3+\sqrt2}4(\sqrt2+1)^n+\frac{3-\sqrt2}4(1-\sqrt2)^n-\frac12(-1)^n$$
In particular, $b_0=1$, $b_1=3$, $b_2=6$, $b_3=16$ and $$b_{54}=516036424787671732778$$ where $54$ is the number of blocks in a standard game of jenga.

EDIT: As @NoName pointed out in the comments, not all configurations are attainable under legal play, since you are not allowed to take bricks from the uppermost filled layer. This effectively means the second layer from the top has to always be filled. Furthermore, the top and third layer combined need to have at least three bricks, so they can not both have only a single brick.

Let us take the opportunity to work out the answer in a slightly different way. By the same reasoning as the generating function, we have a recursive formula for $a_n$ given by the initial condition $(a_0,a_1,a_2)=(1,1,4)$ and the recursion $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}+a_n$. From this, we can calculate any term $a_n$ in a linear number of arithmetic operations with respect to $n$.

We now take attainability into account. Recall that there are $54$ bricks in total. We exhaust all cases for the top few layers. Recall the second layer from the top always has three bricks.

If the top layer also has three bricks, this results in $a_{48}$ configurations. If the top layer has two bricks, this gives three options for the top layer, resulting in $3a_{49}$ configurations. If the top layer has only one brick, this gives three options for the top layer, resulting in $3a_{50}$ configurations. However, we need to subtract the configurations with one brick in both the top layer and the third layer from the top. There are again three options for the top layer, but only one for the second and third layers from the top, resulting in $3a_{49}$ configurations being subtracted.

The resulting total number of configurations is
\begin{align}
a_{48}+3a_{50}&=1425438846754932241+3\cdot8308066439093374804\\&=26349638164035056653
\end{align}

Comment: How is b_3 = 16?

Comment: @jizert If $(l_1,\ldots,l_n)$ denotes configurations with $l_i$ bricks in layer $i$, then there are three configurations with $(1,1,1)$, three with $(1,2)$, nine with $(2,1)$ and one with $(3)$.

Comment: There is one rule of Jenga you forgot: you cannot take from the last *full* layer. If the top layer isn't full, the layer just beneath it must be until you do fill the top layer. Which means b_3 should equal 1, as there are only enough blocks to fill the one and only 'top' layer. I'm not sure what this does to b_54, but I think it would, in effect, subtract three from the index

Comment: @SmileyCraft Can you elaborate? What do you mean by (1, 1, 1)? Wouldn't it be an overcount because each block is not distinct it only matters whether a block is in a position and what that position is

Comment: @jizert I mean there are three configurations with three layers with one brick in each layer. The bottom and middle layer need a brick in the middle and the top layer can have its brick in any of the three spots, giving a total number of three configurations for $(1,1,1)$. For $(2,1)$ there are two layers with two bricks in the bottom layer and one brick in the top layer. The bottom layer has three options for which spot is missing and the top layer has three options for which spot has the brick, giving a total number of nine configurations.

Comment: @NoName That is an interesting point. While I counted all legal configurations, not all of them are attainable under legal play! I'll edit my answer to take this into account.